# Are 2, 3 the only prime numbers that don't have the digit 1 and are palindromes whose squares are also palindromes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, palindrome

While thinking about prime numbers, I noticed that:

$(1)$ Very few prime numbers have squares that are palindromes.

Ex: $2$, $3$, $11$, $101$, $307$

$(2)$ Even rarer are prime numbers that are palindromes whose square are palindromes.

Ex. $2$, $3$, $11$

This inspired me to ask the following questions:

> **$(1)$** Are $2, 3$ the only prime numbers that don't have the digit $1$ and are palindromes whose squares are also palindromes?
>
> **$(2)$** If not, then are there a finite number of these types of these prime numbers.

Comment: [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A225603) for primes $p$ such that both $p$ and $p^2$ are palindromes. It is apparently a conjecture that all such primes $>3$ consist only of zeros and ones.